# Error: Contract with a Signer cannot override from (operation="overrides.from", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.4.1)

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I need to sign my contract with two different parties:

```
await stateMachine.sign({ from: userOne.address });
await stateMachine.sign({ from: userTwo.address });
```

in order to meet the following condition:

```
  function acceptPreCondition(
    bytes32, /*fromState*/
    bytes32 /*toState*/
  ) internal view {
    require(signatures[party1], 'Party 1 did not sign yet');
    require(signatures[party2], 'Party 2 did not sign yet');
  }
```

But when I do so I have the title issue, any idea on how to solve this?
I also tried with the following fix I found from a github issue (does not work):

```
await stateMachine.sign({ from: userOne.address });
await stateMachine.connect();
await stateMachine.sign({ from: userTwo.address });
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
await stateMachine.connect(userOne).sign();
await stateMachine.connect(userTwo).sign();
```